# Наиболее простой способ разбора аргументов командной строки

Tags: c++, mfc, поиск-библиотек

Мне достался старый проект на MFC. Код достаточно запутанный. Чтобы упростить поддержку, буду немного по частям переписывать. Первое, до чего дошли руки, это работа с командной строкой. Там сейчас сделано все вручную, через анализ argc и argv. Собственно вопрос, что есть готовое для C++, что по лицензии можно использовать в коммерческих проектах и что автоматизирует разбор параметров?

Comment: Коллеги, спасибо, пошел смотреть код.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть библиотечка в линуксе, называется readline. Есть версия под [win32](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

Есть С++ вариант в библиотеке boost, называется [program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Варинат с бустом, лично мне, больше нравится.

Да, getopt под win32 тоже имеется [Xgetopt](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/xgetopt.aspx).

Comment: Остановился на бусте: мощная вещь.

Answer (score 5):

Советую посмотреть на unistd.h - и не надо будет тянуть стронние библиотеки, тем более boost.

Answer (score 3):

[CWinApp::ParseCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/64c73803(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри в [исходники основных утилит линукса](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/). И код использовать можно, и принцип узнаешь.